# Unable to execute chef cookbooks in azure RM vm

Tags: azure, chef-infra

I am trying to create azure RM vm using the knife commands given here https://github.com/chef/knife-azure/blob/master/docs/ARM.md. When providing the chef cookbooks in the command,the VM is created but chef cookbooks are not getting executed and there is no error getting displayed as well..it just shows "Creating virtual machine" but after few minutes, process gets over .Any help in solving this issue is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Are you able to ssh to the VM manually after creation?

Comment: yes.I am able to ssh the created VM.

Comment: Does `knife bootstrap` work?

Comment: yes...bootstrapping works and the node gets registered in the chef server as well.